# MemoryLeak appears when using InstantSearch-Android

Tags: android, algolia, instantsearch, instantsearch-android

When I'm using InstantSearch Android, a memory leak appears.

See the following `MainActivity` which leaks memory... `hprof` shows that it is a problem with `com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits`. Does anybody know how to destroy that View when the `Activity` get destroyed?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Searcher searcher;
    InstantSearch helper;

    Hits hits;

    LinearLayout activity_main;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hits= (Hits) findViewById(R.id.hits);
        activity_main= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        searcher = Searcher.create("app_id","secret_key","Items");
        helper = new InstantSearch(this, searcher);
        helper.search();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        searcher=null;

        helper=null;
        hits.clear();

        hits.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        hits.removeAllViews();
        hits.destroyDrawingCache();
        hits.setBackground(null);
        hits.setBackgroundResource(0);
        hits=null;

        activity_main.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        activity_main.removeAllViews();
        activity_main.destroyDrawingCache();
        activity_main.setBackground(null);
        activity_main.setBackgroundResource(0);
        activity_main=null;
        Log.i("AppInfo","Destroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

here is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"
xmlns:algolia="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits
    android:id="@+id/hits"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    algolia:itemLayout="@layout/hits_item"
    algolia:autoHideKeyboard="true"
    algolia:hitsPerPage="20"/>
```

here is my `hits_item.xml`:

```
<layout xmlns:algolia="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profImg"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_video"
            algolia:attribute='@{"profilePic"}'/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hit_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        algolia:attribute='@{"name"}'
        algolia:highlighted='@{true}'/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please add some more info like what is `InstantSearch` and `Searcher`

Comment: InstantSearch and Searcher are classes from InstantSearchAndroid

Comment: Do you have the same issue with one of the example apps? https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples

Comment: yes,with both of them...I do not know if that has something to do with data binding,and this row in com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits: algolia:itemLayout="@layout/hits_item" ...The itemLayout attribute references a layout that will be used to display each item of the results. This layout will contain a View for each attribute of our data that we want to display...I dont understand,how to destroy that layout?

Comment: Hi @bojan, we are still investigating this memory leak. Although we found a first problem and are issuing a fix, we have a hard time reproducing this bug in a deterministic way. Could you share your steps to trigger the memory leak?

Comment: so,when i try destroy this common mainactivity,activity becomes leakedactivity...steps are:start this activity-finish()-leaked activitty! in hprof :mContext in com.algolia.instantsearch. ui.views.Hits... no special steps,simple,can not be destroyed mainactivity when contains com.algolia.instantsearch.ui.views.Hits view...so,is there a way to destroy   Hits view ?

Comment: @bojan we identified the issue and currently working on a fix. I'll get back to you when the change is pushed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just release a fix. If you update to 1.1.4 you can now fix the issue. Just add your activity's `onDestroy` the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // ... your code ...
    searcher.destroy(); // This will clean and release different listeners 
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

You can see it [here](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples/blob/f6208c5478b1409bac7bd025831cb6f11db25a5b/ecommerce/src/main/java/com/algolia/instantsearch/examples/ecommerce/EcommerceActivity.java#L78)

Comment: thank you very much I am very grateful!     but now,when i update on 1.1.4,application cant rebuild,and i get this message:    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'algolia:attribute' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.TextView.
file:D:\MaterialDesign4-poslednje30\app\src\main\res\layout\hits_item.xml
loc:91:33 - 91:39
****\ data binding error ****      please,do you know what it is,why is this happening now?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @bojan We saw this issue before on Android Studio 3.0 but should be fixed now in 1.1.4 https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android/issues/47

Comment: i use android studio 2.2.3... with instantsearch version 1.0.2 works well,but when i upgrade on 1.1.4,i get this error message...

Comment: Can you update your Android Studio to 3.0 or there are technical reasons for not updating ?

Comment: so i only need to update android studio on 3.0  and the problem will be solved? ok i do that,thanx a lot man!

Comment: I update android studio on 3.0 and now everything works perfect,with version 1.1.4,no more memory leak with instantsearch!

Comment: @bojan I edited your question and removed the APP_ID and the API_KEY from the code. You should never post those publically and I advise you to revoke your API key and use a new one.